# AWS Cognito: Creating aws cognito user from express app within lambda function using aws-sdk is giving time out

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am creating a cognito user from serverless express within lambda function using aws-sdk in node js.

I tried with plain lambda function by creating a cognito user, and it works. Below working is my code:

```
const {CognitoIdentityProviderClient, AdminCreateUserCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider");

const region = "us-east-1";
const userPoolId = "us-east-1_xxxxxxx";
const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({region});


/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const email = "dhara@testest.com";
    const password = "dhara?123";
    const name = "Dhara";

    const createUserParams = {
        UserPoolId: userPoolId, // Replace with your User Pool ID
        Username: email,
        TemporaryPassword: password,
        UserAttributes: [
            {
                Name: "email",
                Value: email,
            },
            {
                Name: "preferred_username",
                Value: name,
            },
        ],
        MessageAction: "SUPPRESS",
    };

    try {
        const user = await cognitoClient.send(new AdminCreateUserCommand(createUserParams));
        console.log("User created successfully:", user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    }
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
};
```

The above code successfully creates a user in cognito and gives success response. But when I try the same with serverless express and lambda function, it just gives time out—not creating users at all. Below is the code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')

const {CognitoIdentityProviderClient, AdminCreateUserCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider");

const region = "us-east-1";
const userPoolId = "us-east-1_xxxxxx";
const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({region});

// declare a new express app
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
  next()
});

app.post('/api/v1/users/test', async function(req, res) {
  const createUserParams = {
    UserPoolId: userPoolId, // Replace with your User Pool ID
    Username: "dhara@testest.com",
    TemporaryPassword: "Dhara?123",
    UserAttributes: [
      {
        Name: "email",
        Value: "dhara@testest.com",
      },
      {
        Name: "preferred_username",
        Value: "Test",
      },
    ],
    MessageAction: "SUPPRESS",
  };
  try {
    console.log('try starts');
    const response = await cognitoClient.send(new AdminCreateUserCommand(createUserParams));
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
  res.status(201).json({ status:"success"});
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("App started")
});

module.exports = app
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws-serverless-express` has been out of usage and been deprecated for a very long time. The issues you see are more than likely related to that. AWS split off this package to the company Vendia and the new instructions are available on the GitHub page: [Announcement](https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express#aws-serverless-express-is-now-under-the-stewardship-of-vendia)

Further, there's not anything immediately wrong with code you wrote, so you'll need to create a minimal repo to actually find the problem. Start deleting code.

For what it's worth, we much prefer this smaller, optimized and simpler version of the Vendia package: [aws-architect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-architect)

The last thing to note us that almost assuredly you should never need to manually create users in a lambda function. The users will automatically be created by sending the user agent through to Cognito to sign up in the first place. So there is a bit of an unexpected situation here in your implementation as well. Changing that would fundamentally remove the problem.

And if this is going to be your production usage, you might want to be careful around the [common concerns with Cognito](https://dev.to/authress/aws-cognito-dont-go-to-production-38h3).